# How to read data from serial port by Angular Web Application?

Tags: angular, serial-port, user-input, rfid, input-devices

I have a simple Arduino device that created for reading RFID. It returns UID of the RFID tag to serial port of client PC.I need to read that value returned by Arduino device using Angular web application. It is not **AngularJS** .It is **Angular 14** with **TypeScript**.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the webserial api?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. But maybe using a NodeJs script you can access the data from this port and then send it to angular.

[Can i monitor an existing serial port communication with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333607/can-i-monitor-an-existing-serial-port-communication-with-node-js)

I hope it can help you

Comment: It is smart patient management system that created for hospitals using Angular. I need to give a RFID to patients. When doctors need to view patient's profile and medical history they can simply scan RFID and view data using this web app. This answer is really helps me I will try it.Thank you !